You might as well be hanged for a sheep as for a lamb

You might as well be hanged for a sheep as for a lamb. (An English proverb)

Can I rephrase the proverb above as below?

You might be hanged for a sheep as well as for a lamb.


You might as well is a fixed phrase which means you will incur no extra pain or adverse consequences if you choose to'. So your rephrasing does not work.

See this question, and this explanation of the proverb.

Thanks Kate. I asked this question because I wanted to know if I could shift the embedded 'as well' from 'might as well' to 'as for a lamb.'

If you were going to move as well you should reverse the order: "You might be hanged as well for a lamb as for a sheep."  The punishment for stealing a lamb would not be less than the punishment for stealing a sheep. The implication being you have nothing more to lose by stealing a sheep, so steal the sheep.  There, "might" has the meaning "There's nothing stopping them from hanging you".  Possibility when there are no prohibitive conditions. You could substitute "can":  You can be hanged for stealing a lamb just as you can be hanged for stealing a sheep.

TimR, iF your inverted version is possible, then the 'might as well' is not a fixed phrase such as MichaelHarvey's comment. And, in this case, the shifted 'as well' is not relelated to 'might' anymore. In other words, it means an isolated 'also'.

It may be worth pointing out that in modern times, when people are not (at least in Britain) executed for theft, the proverb is usually used about everyday 'crimes' such as staying an extra half-hour in the pub before returning to the marital home, or stopping for a Starbucks on the way to the office when you are already a few minutes late.

@gomadeng  That is not a valid conclusion. The fixed phrase highlights the hanging and so it has a more "devil-may-care" attitude than the other versions. Or at least it wears that attitude "on its sleeve". They might both express the same attitude, but one does so more directly than the other.

Under the 18th century Bloody Code, many property crimes were treated as capital crimes.

@gomadeng And "as well" in this usage is not simply "also".  It means "equally".  And it has that meaning regardless of its location.  It's not the same as "I have a cat. -- I do as well"    and the meanings are different because in the sheep/lamb context the situation admits degree whereas in the "have a cat" context there is no sense of degree.

I asked this question because I wanted to know if I could shift the embedded 'as well' from 'might as well' to 'as for a lamb.' I know you did - and, because might as well is a set phrase, you can't split it.

@KateBunting What about: We might as well give it to him as give it to her. (to mean Whether we give it to him or her doesn't matter.)?

That's fine, though most speakers would omit the second give it.
